# /var/log/auth.log not logging failed ssh attempts

Tags: ssh, logging, authentication

I'm trying to go failed (either incorrect username, password, or both) on my server.

I changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config from

```
# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH 
LogLevel INFO
```

to

```
# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH 
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

and have since tried multiple ssh attempts with both existing and non-exisiting users with random passwords thus failing. When checking /var/log/auth.log nothing appears and it is entirely blank.

What am I missing? Does some other process need to also be install and running on my system? I'm running Ubuntu.

Any help or guidance on this matter is more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart sshd?

Comment: What does your syslog configuration look like? This would probably be a file at `/etc/syslog.conf` or `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`

Comment: @StefanLasiewski the first 2 are empty and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` says "$AddUnixListenSocket /var/spool/postfix/dev/log"

Comment: @Georgejnr : If that is the case, it appears that the syslog configuration on your system is broken. There is normally a syslog file under /etc/syslog.conf or /etc/rsyslog.conf , and normally there should be more then one file under /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf . Does `ps aux` show a syslog process?

Comment: @StefanLasiewski no it is not listed in ps aux. The previous sysadmin went a little rogue and broke a few things I believe on purpose. Think this could be part of it? How do I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Try reinstalling rsyslog. Might need to 'remove', 'purge' then reinstall. See http://superuser.com/questions/102449/how-to-reinstall-a-package-using-apt-get

Comment: I'm going to have to continue this tomorrow at work. The reinstall after purge is failing `invoke-rc.d: initscript rsyslog, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing rsyslog (--configure)` Thanks for your time and I will update once i've had a play :-)

Comment: Hi I installed syslog-ng and that has worked if you want to create an answer around that... thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LogLevel generally (apparently application dependent) refers to one of the defined severity levels supported by the system logging process (syslog).  So change it back and restart the sshd server.

Now if you are not getting the output, you need to look at the system /etc/syslog.conf and see what MINIMUM loglevel the AUTH type of requests are being logged and to what file.  The errors might be going to a different log file. OR you might not be logging these errors due to the syslog.conf configuration for the AUTH service.  For more information consult the man pages on and syslog.conf.

Comment: From [sshd_config(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) LogLevel: Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages from sshd(8).  The possible values are: QUIET, FATAL, ERROR, INFO, *VERBOSE*, DEBUG, DEBUG1, DEBUG2, and DEBUG3.

Comment: my /syslog.conf is empty. I must add that I am taking over someone else's system and it seems that they didn't do a very good job of setting it up. Does the lack of syslog.conf mean that I am missing a service? (thanks for your response)

Comment: File is in /etc......it is possible that you might not be logging anything.

Comment: About VERBOSE in sshd_config....my mistake, but its not a syslog log level which is commonly asked for in many of the programs I have dealt with.

Comment: leaving VERBOSE still in my sshd_config and running sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart it still isn't logging. Am I being dumb about something?

Comment: is there a lag?

Comment: Then you should address it by close examination and modification of your /etc/syslog.conf file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6608/discussion-between-georgejnr-and-mdpc)

Comment: What is the full solution ? If we haven't syslog ?

Answer (score 7):

When I had the same problem on Debian, I found I had to restart rsyslogd:

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

(Your syslogd program may vary.)

The it started writing to /var/log/auth.log again.

Perhaps it had stopped logging after a disk full event, I'm not sure.

See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1059854/comments/9

Comment: This worked for me, but using systemctl instead to restart the syslog service (Debian sid using inetutils-syslogd).  `systemctl restart inetutils-syslogd.service`

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was with the ownership of the `/var/log/auth.log` file. It was owned by `root:root` but must be `syslog:adm`. Change with

```
sudo chown syslog:adm /var/log/auth.log
```

It appears to be a common problem with the newly created systems - there were more log files, which had this issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case there was no diskspace on left on the root file-system  `/`, which you can check for with `df -h`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a daemon like sshlog (I'm a contributor for this project) which monitors successful and failing ssh requests as well as the commands executed.  The nice thing about this approach is that you can configure how you would like these events logged/alerted.

For example, you could configure it to report all failed login attempts and send that to a remote syslog, and send any sudo attempts to Slack alerts.

In this case the config would look like:

```
events:
  - event: log_all_failed_connections
    triggers:
      - connection_auth_failed
    actions:
      - action: syslog_to_localhost
        plugin: syslog_action
        server_address: remote_server_addr
        port: 514
        udp: True
        output_json: False
        program_name: sshlog

  - event: sudo_successful
    triggers: [ 'command_finish']
    filters:
      command_name: 'sudo'
      command_exit_code: '= 0'
    actions:
      - action: send_to_slack
        plugin: slack_action
        slack_webhook_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/x/y/z'
```

More config examples are available here: https://github.com/sshlog/agent/tree/master/daemon/config_samples