# Where and how can I get the list of the failed login and sudoers in CentOS v8?

Tags: linux, centos, centos8

People,

For CentOS v8 Linux, where and how can I get the event logs for the:

1. Failed SSH (port TCP/22) connection
2. Failed sudoers

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you re-enable rsyslog as recommended a few days ago?

Comment: @MichaelHampton personalized service! That's great!

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, no, does it means there is nothing logged until I enable it first on a newly installed CentOS v8?

Comment: See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/454742/var-log-auth-log-not-logging-failed-ssh-attempts) as well. You should really follow the advice from qualified contributors here, who are, hem, what's better than "senior", well, "Sensei" System Engineers...

Comment: No, there are logs, i.e. the journal, but as I said the other day they aren't persistent by default. You have to take some action to get persistent logging, whether it's using rsyslog, or shipping journal entries somewhere else. The journal does have logs of failed sudo and ssh connections but they are far more detailed than would normally be useful, and sorting out the useful entries turns out to be a bit painful. Looking through files created by rsyslog turns out to be a lot easier.

Comment: That' does make sense @MichaelHampton, I will enable the rsyslog as per the suggestion. Thanks man.

Comment: Thank you as well to @e2-e4 for the suggestion.

Comment: Regarding your 1st question, you don't need rsyslog for this task. You can simply do `journalctl -u sshd` to see messages related to sshd. For failed attempts, `journalctl -u sshd | grep -i fail`.

Comment: @Krackout, many thanks man, this is what I need now. You're very helpful.